# different types of initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

Can somebody make me understand the difference between the below code snippets.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    }  
    return self; 
}
```

And

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

The apple documentation says when instantiating a view controller from a storyboard use initWithCoder. Please can someone write a sample code using initWithCoder method to initiate a view controller.

I am actually new to ios programming so just wannna know the difference.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The most important difference is that initWithCoder: is called when a VC is pulled from a storyboard, and initWithNibName is not. You can, for all intents and purposes, ignore the `WithCoder:` bit (except passing it to `[super initWithCoder:decoder]`). The method is part of the object archiving/serialization libraries in Cocoa, and they are used when an instantiated object needs to be archived/unarchived.

It helps to think of it this way: your ViewController is actually instantiated and and initialized *when you build your app in Xcode*, and then archived **to your storyboard**. Then at runtime, the storyboard is treated like an archive, and your job is more like "re-initialize from archive" than a traditional init.

Answer (score 0):

It typically gets called whenever it's is being created from IB (the nib, or from a storyboard), however it is also called when the object is archived or serialized (look at NSUnarchiver).

As far as implementing it goes, you can just treat it as you would with
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
However, you just need to make sure you pass your extra parameter to the super class when you call it:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self) {
        // do your setup here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

You're probably never going to call this, but interface builder will if you use a custom class/view embedded in the nib.  If you're initializing it in code, you should use initWithNibName.